# Connect Microsoft Access Database with MATLAB AppDesigner

Tags: ms-access, matlab-compiler, matlab-app-designer, matlab-gui

I am working on a project where I am trying to create a GUI App with MATLAB AppDesigner. This App should be able to fetch data from Microsoft Access Database (.accdb). Can someone help me how to connect the Database with AppDesigner? I have explored the Database Explorer App, can import data and perform query; also can generate MATLAB script for query using the Database explorer app. I am not sure how to connect the database with the AppDesigner. Thank you for your help.